# JBOSS SSL configuration ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, jboss, keytool

I've used self-signed SSL configuration on JBOSS 5.1 GA

I'm using Google chrome 43.0.2357.124 on windows 7 and getting the following error.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
A secure connection cannot be established because this site uses an unsupported protocol.

Note: The same configuration works in internet explorer.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Did you find any solution? I am using node.js and Express.js.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663597/creating-ssl-requests-with-node-js-and-express